# Log Level of Micronaut Application changed after update

Tags: log4j2, micronaut

I just migrated my project from Micronaut 3.6.3 to 4.2.0
We use Log4J2 as logger.
Since the update, all micronaut debug logs are printed to the console, even if root logger ist set to INFO. I could not find anything in the changelogs regarding this issue.

my log4J2.xml:

```
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsolePrint" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <LevelPatternSelector defaultPattern="%style{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}}{#00736d} [%t] %highlight{%-5level} %logger{36} - %msg\n">
                    <PatternMatch key="ERROR" pattern="%style{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}}{#00736d} [%t] %highlight{%-5level} %logger{36} -%msg%n %highlight{%ex{full}}\n" />
                </LevelPatternSelector>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="rollingFileAppender" fileName="${env:LOG_DIR:-.logs}/index.log" filePattern="${env:LOG_DIR:-.logs}/%d{MM-dd-yyyy}/%i-log-%d{HH-mm-ss}.log" immediateFlush="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n %ex{full}"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>


    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsolePrint"/>
            <SystemPropertyArbiter propertyName="MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS" propertyValue="development">
                <AppenderRef ref="rollingFileAppender"/>
            </SystemPropertyArbiter>
            <SystemPropertyArbiter propertyName="MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS" propertyValue="production">
                <AppenderRef ref="rollingFileAppender"/>
            </SystemPropertyArbiter>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```